# transaction_id is invalid in spree when integrate braintree payment gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I am new spree and I add new payment gateway brain tree sandbox.

But when I approve my payment in admin side it give me transaction_id is invalid error in payment controller fire method.]

> Argument Error (transaction_id is invalid):
>       app/controllers/spree/admin/payments_controller_decorator `fire'.

and my second question is that how can I prevent my specific params not pass to payment gateway.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer at Braintree. I am not certain what your exact issue is without more information, but if you take a look at our [client library](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby/blob/4e6fbb048b5ad27614b938177a9875a7b229f8fd/lib/braintree/transaction_gateway.rb#L102) you can see that this error is raised when you provide a transaction id that consists of non-alphanumeric characters:

```
raise ArgumentError, "transaction_id is invalid" unless transaction_id =~ /\A[0-9a-z]+\z/
```

If this does not resolve your issue, you should reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for further assistance.